# Moving from ASP.Net to PHP - Encoding

Tags: php, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

First.
Sorry for my english, i'm brazilian..

I need to move from ASP.NET to PHP, and in ASP.Net have this:

```
public void Write(string str)
{
     byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str.ToString());
     output.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}
```

and, in PHP I tried this:

```
function Write($String)
{
     $data = mb_convert_encoding($String, "UTF8", "Unicode");
     return $data;
}
```

However, it does not return the same message..

I use this in ASP.NET with XML.

EDIT¹:
Output is a MemoryStream

Thanks,

Comment: what is your input and what is the expected output?

Comment: output is: "MemoryStream", i use this with .aspx, look: " GResponse.Write(xml.ToString());"

Comment: Why are you using Unicode as the $from_encoding parameter?

Answer (score 1):

```
// php manual
string mb_convert_encoding ( string $str , string $to_encoding [, mixed $from_encoding = mb_internal_encoding() ] )
```

Your function no need "Unicode":

```
function Write($String)
{
     $data = mb_convert_encoding($String, "ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8");
     return $data;
}
```